# Merge two columns containing NA values in complementing rows

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

Suppose I have this dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(
    x=c(1, NA, NA, 4, 5, NA),
    y=c(NA, 2, 3, NA, NA, 6)
```

which looks like this

```
   x  y
1  1 NA
2 NA  2
3 NA  3
4  4 NA
5  5 NA
6 NA  6
```

How can I merge the two columns into one? Basically the NA values are in complementary rows. It would be nice to also obtain (in the process) a `flag` column containing `0` if the entry comes from `x` and `1` if the entry comes from `y`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can try using the `coalesce` function from the `dplyr` package:

```
df$merged <- coalesce(df$x, df$y)
df$flag <- ifelse(is.na(df$y), 0, 1)
df

   x  y merged flag
1  1 NA      1    0
2 NA  2      2    1
3 NA  3      3    1
4  4 NA      4    0
5  5 NA      5    0
6 NA  6      6    1
```

Comment: @Euler_Salter Dplyr's `coalesce` likely is borrowed from the SQL coalesce function, which has been in use for 30+ years.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `base R` methods with `max.col` on the logical matrix to get the column index, `cbind` with row index and extract the values that are not NA

```
df$merged <- df[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), max.col(!is.na(df)))]
df$flag <- +(!is.na(df$y))
df
#   x  y merged flag
#1  1 NA      1    0
#2 NA  2      2    1
#3 NA  3      3    1
#4  4 NA      4    0
#5  5 NA      5    0
#6 NA  6      6    1
```

---

Or we can use `fcoalesce` from `data.table` which is written in `C` and is multithreaded for numeric and factor types.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, c('merged', 'flag' ) := .(fcoalesce(x, y), +(!is.na(y)))]
df
#    x  y merged flag
#1:  1 NA      1    0
#2: NA  2      2    1
#3: NA  3      3    1
#4:  4 NA      4    0
#5:  5 NA      5    0
#6: NA  6      6    1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using dplyr as follows;

```
library(dplyr)

# Creating dataframe
df <- 
  data.frame(
    x = c(1, NA, NA, 4, 5, NA),
    y = c(NA, 2, 3, NA, NA, 6))

df %>%
  # If x is null then replace it with y
  mutate(merged = coalesce(x, y),
         # If x is null then put 1 else put 0
         flag = if_else(is.na(x), 1, 0))

# x  y merged flag
# 1 NA      1    0
# NA  2      2    1
# NA  3      3    1
# 4 NA      4    0
# 5 NA      5    0
# NA  6      6    1
```

Comment: You don't really the `if_else()`as `is.na(x)` is TRUE and you can convert it to 1.

Comment: Yes true, but in general I believe that using if_else is a better practice as in general it is more strict and it makes the output much more predictable when reading the code.